# Root running a command, but force the command to write data as another user

Tags: linux, file-permissions

To make this question clearer, let me explain my use case.

I have a MySQL database (so an application) that runs with the `mysql` user, and the database has 2 `root` users:

- One accessible from a tcp connection, but has no privileges
- One accessible from a local socket, and have all privileges

In order to backup the data, I'm running a command as `root` so that it can connect using the socket and execute queries, so the created data is owned by `root` which I don't want as I need to access (read/write) it as the `mysql` user.

Is there a way to execute a command as a user, but force/change the `uid` or permissions of the files written on the disk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution would be to create an empty file owned by mysql then use ">>" to append the file rather then create it.

I have not tried it, but instead of using tee, you could use cat -

```
  $ mysqldump phpmyadmin | sudo -u mysql cat >> mysqldump.sql
```

Or create the file or folder and set the permissions **before** the script use it.

Comment: This will create the file with root as the owner.

Comment: I think you're right davidgo, but in your example you uses `>` instead of `>>` so it replaces the file.

Comment: I'm actually trying this option. I've created the folder for the backups and did a `chown` to `mysql` and I'm now checking if it's working or not.

Comment: Thank you for the correction - yes, it should have been >> as you pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

Pipe the output of `mysqldump` into `tee` and run `tee` under your target user.

```
$ mysqldump phpmyadmin |sudo -u mysql tee mysqldump.sql >/dev/null
$ ls -l *.sql
-rw-r--r-- 1 mysql mysql 19071 Nov 22 09:13 mysqldump.sql
```

The `> /dev/null` prevents additional output to the console.

Comment: Interesting! I'll give it a try and come back, thank you!

Comment: Sorry I haven't try this one, but creating the folder, setting the permissions before the script runs looks easier so I've accepted the davidgo answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `chown` the files after your backup operation.

However, the preferred option is to create another database user for taking backups, and log in to that user with normal user account. You should not use `root` account for anything that does not explicitly need all privileges.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but `chown` would have to be executed after the backup is done, so there is a period of time where the backup is own by `root` (ultimately I would do so if I can't find any other way). I'm looking for a way to get the backup file always accessible by the `mysql` user.

Comment: You will get backup files accessible by `mysql` user when you run `mysqldump` as the `mysql` user. You need to setup your database so that you can run `mysqldump` with the `mysql` user.